# Flink can not send http request to S3 bucket on localstack

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-flink, localstack

I'm trying to call the `getObject` api to get an external file on S3 bucket0  within my Flink job, but it keeps getting a SdkException from my localstack setup:

```
 org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.SdkClientException:
 Unable to execute HTTP request: mybucketName.s3.localstack
```

This is how I created my resources with docker compose and localstack

```
container_name: localstack
image: localstack/localstack:0.12.15
ports:
  - "14566:4566"
expose:
  - "4566"
environment:
  - DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
  - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=test
  - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=test
  - EDGE_PORT=4566
  - SERVICES=s3
  - AWS_CBOR_DISABLE=1
```

I have tried to replace the endpoint with http://localstack:4566 and http://s3.localstack:4566, but I still see the error

```
import org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
    
AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration =
        new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(
            "http://s3.localstack:4566",   // also tried localstack:4566 and 127.0.0.1:4566 etc..
            region);

s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
        .withEndpointConfiguration(endpointConfiguration)
        .build()


S3Object s3Object = s3Client.getObject(bucketName, objectLocation);
```

Anyone knows why I'm getting this issue? Sorry the SdkException only shows unable to execute HTTP and does not output lots for context/info. Thank you.

Comment: I'd expect "http://localhost:14566" with that port line, unless you're trying to access the localstack from within the same container.

Comment: @AnonCoward I tried using localhost:14566, but still got the same message: org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: bucketName.localhost

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I have found the solution, I should call .enablePathStyleAccess() in my client

```
    AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
        .withEndpointConfiguration(endpointConfiguration)
        .enablePathStyleAccess()
        .build()
```

Please refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65189248/aws-s3-with-localstack-return-500-in-a-java-application)